# How do I correctly add the Google Optimize page-hiding snippet to AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, single-page-application, google-optimize

I can successfully trigger optimize experiments to work by using the following code:

```
$rootScope.$watch(function () {
    $timeout(function () {
      dataLayer.push({ event: 'optimize.activate' });
    }, 0, false);
  });
```

I have also added the page hiding snippet [taken from here](https://support.google.com/optimize/answer/6314801)

But when I run Google Optimize diagnostics I get the following warning
[image: Warning]

I actually don't experience any page flicker although it also says that only users with slow connections experience this.

Answer (score 0):

For the page-hiding snippet you inserted the wrong GTM- ID

> Note: Replace GTM-XXXXXX with your Tag Manager container ID (not your Optimize container ID).

Use the GTM- ID inside the Tag Manager Snippet.